# Query Blocks with SELECT INTO

Tags: sql, oracle

QUERY is self explanatory.

```
DECLARE 
    ID NUMBER (10); 
    ISFIRST NUMBER (1);
BEGIN

    SELECT M.ID, M.ISFIRST 
    INTO ID, ISFIRST
    FROM MERCHANT M
    WHERE M.PHONE = :1;

    IF (ISFIRST=1) THEN 
        SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER C WHERE C.ISFIRST=1 AND C.MERCHANTID = ID;
    ELSE 
        SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER C WHERE C.ISFIRST=0 AND C.MERCHANTID = ID;
    END IF;

END;
```

This query gives me "PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement".
I need to select data from CUSTOMER table depending on MERCHANT.ISFIRST and MERCHANT.ID.
Any workaround or little explanation what went wrong would be appreciated.

PS: The problem is solved with UNION ALL statement. This question needs to be closed.

Comment: Why no just have `WHERE C.ISFIRST=ISFIRST`?

Comment: It's not necessary to SHOUT your questions here. Also, please don't put tag information in your title. The tagging system here is very good at classifying things, and doesn't need help. :-) Please see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SELECT` statements have nothing wrong, **except** that you are not doing **anything** with them.  I mean the last two.  What do you want them to do?  Produce a result that is going to be discarded?  PL/SQL does not allow it.

Just to try if this is correct, you can pick a single field and do `SELECT {aField} INTO {aVariable}` instead of `SELECT *`.

```
    IF( ISFIRST = 1 ) THEN 
        SELECT {aField} INTO {aVariable} FROM CUSTOMER C WHERE C.ISFIRST=1 AND C.MERCHANTID = ID;
    ELSE 
        SELECT {aField} INTO {aVariable} FROM CUSTOMER C WHERE C.ISFIRST=0 AND C.MERCHANTID = ID;
    END IF;
```

Don't forget to declare {aVariable}!!!

Comment: Block query doesn't work. All I need from the QUERY is to get data from CUSTOMER table as I mentioned. I assumed that this query would give me a data set from CUSTOMER table but instead it gives me error message. Doing things with the result would not be handled in query. I'm going to use the result in C# code.

Comment: @NarankhuuBoldbaatar  That's a completely different question.  I can't answer it in a comment.  I do have space to say the two main solutions are pipeline functions and cursors as a return type.  Google for "How do I return a rowset from an Oracle PL/SQL procedure".

Comment: I treated this block query as it was a single SELECT query. Normally, whatever a single select query return that's handled in C++ code then comes to C# form as a Data Table. Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with PL/SQL and have no access to C++ code section here. @Mario Rossi, now my question becomes fairly simple. What does a single SELECT statement return? A cursor?

Comment: @NarankhuuBoldbaatar  I can't answer in such short space.  Open a new question and add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query will do the same thing :

```
SELECT C.* 
FROM CUSTOMER C 
INNER JOIN MERCHANT M ON C.MERCHANTID = M.ID AND 
                         C.ISFIRST = M.ISFIRST AND
                         M.PHONE = :1;
```